# PHP Merge array into multidimensional array by key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge

This is my array:

```
$recid[$row['Rec_Mgmt_id']] = array
(
    'program'=> $row['Program'],
    'doc' => $row['Date_of_clinic'],
    'name' => $row["FName"]. " " . $row['LName'],
    'claim' => $row['ClaimNum'],
    'md' => $row['Doctor'],
    'prognosis' => $row['Prognosis'],
    'workStatus' => $row['WorkStatus'],
    'service' => array
    (
        $row['Service_Requested_id'] => array
        (
            'name' => $row['Service'], 
            'site' => $row['Service_Site'], 
            'status' => $row['Approval_Status'], 
            'denial' => $row['Reason_Denial'], 
            'approvalDate' => $row['Date_Approval'], 
            'txIn' => $row['TX_Intake_Date'], 
            'txOut' => $row['TX_Discharge_Date'], 
            'comments' => $row['Comments']
        )
    )
);
```

How would I add the below array as another 'service' array?

```
array($row['Service_Requested_id'] => array
    (
    'name' => $row['Service'], 
    'site' => $row['Service_Site'], 
    'status' => $row['Approval_Status'], 
    'denial' => $row['Reason_Denial'], 
    'approvalDate' => $row['Date_Approval'], 
    'txIn' => $row['TX_Intake_Date'], 
    'txOut' => $row['TX_Discharge_Date'], 
    'comments' => $row['Comments']
    )
);
```

Maybe it is because I'm feeling a little brain dead..but I have tried numerous approaches and I am not able to get this added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i fully understand your question but I think this will do what you need.

```
$recid[$row['Rec_Mgmt_id']]['service'][$row['Service_Requested_id']] = array (      
     'name' => $row['Service'], 
     'site' => $row['Service_Site'], 
     'status' => $row['Approval_Status'], 
     'denial' => $row['Reason_Denial'], 
     'approvalDate' => $row['Date_Approval'], 
     'txIn' => $row['TX_Intake_Date'], 
     'txOut' => $row['TX_Discharge_Date'], 
     'comments' => $row['Comments']);
```

Comment: This might make you end up with an array of an array.  I would remove the `array($row['Service_Requested_id'] => ` and its closing array bracket.

Comment: You wouldn't want to append the new array, but instead set the new array under the specific key.`$recid...['service'][$row['Service_Requested_id']] = array('name'=>...);` Or use array_merge to add the new array.

Comment: Wow...I am really brain dead...I did exactly that..but instead added the array (service_request_id) into the service...$recid[$row['Rec_Mgmt_id']]['service']=array($row['Service_Requested_id'] => array(.....))...